# Specific Ads in Android application

Tags: android, ads

I am developing an application and I want to integrate Ads inside it.

How? I am aware of AdMob if I am right it gives an option to put Ads using AdWords(=Key words???).

But... If I want an external company to pay me for putting the Ads inside it, how do I do it. I think AdMob does not support the Specific Ads feature. 
I can create a webservice that will D/L the banners, but I will need all the UI feature (The Ad moving and disapppearing etc. that already suppoted by the Ads packages).

I will also need the same for iPhone version ( for minimum logic changes etc)

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Admob's [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/). AFAIK it should work with the same platforms that admob works on.